# SQL (Postgres) function definition - RETURNS

Tags: sql, database, function, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a very simple PostgreSQL function, though I keep getting a very strange syntax error. The syntax I use is different from anything I have seen online (though this is the one the textbook uses), and thus I can't figure out why it fails...

This is the SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gsum(graphID integer)
    RETURNS integer
    BEGIN
        DECLARE total integer DEFAULT 0
        SELECT sum(weight) INTO total
        FROM Edge
        WHERE gno = graphID
    RETURN total;
    END;
```

The error is:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
LINE 3:  BEGIN
         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 68
```

Comment: Your syntax looks like PSM - but it is wrong in PostgreSQL - There more languages than one are supported (and it needs little bit strange syntax for CREATE FUNCTION). PLpgSQL is based on ADA language - or more on PL/SQL - what is simplified ADA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic mistakes:

- [`DECLARE` must come before `BEGIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-structure.html).
- Statements need to be terminated with `;`.
- Function body of a plpgsql function is a string and needs to be quoted. Use dollar-quoting to avoid complications with quotes in the body.
- Missing keyword `AS`.
- Missing language declaration `LANGUAGE plpgsql`.
- Type mismatch.
- You don't need a default.
- This would still return `NULL` if the sum is `NULL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gsum(graphID integer)
  RETURNS integer AS
$func$
DECLARE
   total integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT sum(weight)::int INTO total
   FROM   edge
   WHERE  gno = graphID;

   RETURN COALESCE(total, 0);
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And you'd better use a simple SQL function for this like [@Clodoaldo advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24782219/939860). Just add `COALESCE()`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be plain SQL in instead of plpgsql

```
create or replace function gsum(graphid integer)
returns bigint as $$

    select sum(weight) as total
    from edge
    where gno = graphid;

$$ language sql;
```

Notice that if `weight` is integer `sum` will return `bigint` not `integer`.

Comment: Is it possible to accomplish the task with the type of syntax I use?

Comment: @byteSlayer Check Erwin's answer

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  gsum(graphID integer)
    RETURNS integer AS
    $BODY$        
DECLARE 
    total integer DEFAULT 0;
    BEGIN

        SELECT sum(weight) INTO total
        FROM Edge
        WHERE gno = graphID;
    RETURN total;
    END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```